# What does it mean to "verify SW requirements related to safety, security and critically are correct, as shown by rigorous methods"?

Tags: software-development, requirements

I have been given a list of criteria to verify our requirements against (I found out they took it from an ISO standard) and there is one I have no clue what to do with:

> the software requirements related to safety, security, and criticality are correct as shown by suitably rigorous methods.

I am not even sure what is meant by that.

What is this about, how can I verify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You verify the software requirements related to these criteria in the same way as you would verify the software requirements for *any* criteria; by replaying the documented software requirements back to the relevant personnel with responsibility for those items and working through any variations with them until you have arrived at an agreed set of requirements.

So for example, work with members of the Security team to look at the areas of the software requirements that overlap on the areas of responsibility of the Security team. This could be done by a meeting, a workshop, a teleconference or even by passing the software specifications to them remotely and asking them to review and sign off on the specification from a Security point of view.

In all cases ensure you have documented any changes required to the software specifications, once you have reached agreement with each party on their approved form, and ensure you have a paper trail containing an agreement from each party that you have accurately represented their needs in the requirement and their approval of the specification (this is the 'rigour' mentioned in your brief).